# Extra lines in Sketchup DTM when using stamp tool

Tags: sketchup, dem

I have a DTM in Sketchup. I am trying to use the stamp tool to make a level area on which to build a building.

However, when I use the stamp tool lots of extra lines appear on the DTM seemingly at random (I realise these are the lines that form the DTM but only *some* of them appear).

The lines are *not*  hidden geometry. It may be that this is the reason they are showing - they aren't hidden and the rest of the lines are. If this is the case I'm not sure how to hide them again without exploding the DTM, which I don't want to do.

Can anybody tell me why this is happening? Can anyone tell me how to prevent it?

**Example:**

Left: Original DTM

Right: DTM after using stamp tool.

*Note: The images are of different parts of the DTM! My problem isn't that the DTM is changed (the stamp tool works exactly as it should), it is just that the lines become visible.*

[image]

Comment: Did the stamping created another sanbox? Do these line change in any way when you Soften Edges with both the Smooth normals and Soften coplanar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the new sandbox (TIN) and select Soften/Smooth edges. check on both "Smooth normals" and Soften coplanar and move the slider (Angle between normals) to the right.  SketchUp has the ability to adjust smoothness of surfaces.